# Typescript overloading function with generics, similar to Promise.all

Tags: typescript

I am creating a function which may take multiple arguments, all of different types and returns a result which contains the same types as the arguments, just differently wrapped.

I have more or less copied the type declaration of Promise.all, which looks like the following (removed jsdoc for readability):

```
all<T1, T2, T3>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3]>;
all<T1, T2>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>]): Promise<[T1, T2]>;
all<T>(values: (T | PromiseLike<T>)[]): Promise<T[]>;
```

This is the overloading that I came up with:

```
export function matchAll<T1, T2, T3>(
    args: [Maybe<T1>, Maybe<T2>, Maybe<T3>]
): Matcher<[T1, T2, T3]>;
export function matchAll<T1, T2>(
    args: [Maybe<T1>, Maybe<T2>]
): Matcher<[T1, T2]>;
export function matchAll<T>(args: Maybe<T>[]): Matcher<[T]> { ... }
```

Now typescript is showing me the error `This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.ts(2394)` , always for the **uppermost** type declaration, not those below. Also while using the function, typescript appears to use the declarations correctly.

What can I do to surpress the error/fix the problem?

Comment: Please consider modifying your code to constitute a [mcve] where the only issue is the one you're facing.  As it stands there are undefined types like `Maybe` and `Matcher`.  My *guess* is that your implementation signature should return `Matcher<T[]>` and not `Matcher<[T]>`, but since I have no idea what `Matcher` is, that might not work for you.  Good luck!

Comment: The code behind it shoukd not really matter, if the stuff that I return is actually of the wrong type, the error would be at the return type of the function.Also I am sure I tried `Matcher<T[]>` before, but I guess I did not, fixed it for me, thank you @jcalz

Comment: "The code behind it should not really matter"... the types matter, though.  If `type Matcher<T extends any[]> = T[number];` then there's no error.  If `type Matcher<T> = string` then there's no error.  The point of a [mcve] is to demonstrate the issue you're facing to others, so that they don't have to make guesses, and you have a better chance of getting an answer.